# Spark streaming custom receiver memory issue

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, spark-streaming

I have a 10 nodes cluster with Spark 1.6, one Master and 9 Worker and I'm running a Streaming job with a custom receiver.

The receiver is created randomly on one of the node and its memory usage is high.

Computations on Executors are consuming high amount of memory too and regulary the Executor on the node with the Receiver gets removed.

In the picture below you can see how Executors are removed when Executor and Receiver combined memory usage is too high.

[image]
I was wondering if I can instantiate the Receiver on a node without an Executor so their memory usage combined would not result in executor removed.